# Select from 3 tables with two order by before two group by

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I try to get a list of products with each newest and lowest offer price

**Table product**:

```
id | name
```

**Table offer**:

```
id | product_id | price | created | dealer_id
```

**Table invalids**:

```
id | offer_id | status
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT offer.product_id , offer.price
        FROM offer 
        LEFT JOIN invalids 
        ON offer.id = invalids.offer_id 
        WHERE invalids.id IS NULL 
        GROUP BY offer.dealer_id
        ORDER BY offer.created DESC
    ) o 
ON o.product_id = product.id 
ORDER BY product.name
```

I have tried an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32658/3 with this offer values:

```
(`id`, `price`, `dealer_id`, `product_id`, `created`)  
(1,12.60,1,1,'2015-05-17 08:44:45'),  
(2,13.00,1,1,'2015-08-17 08:44:45'),  
(3,20.00,1,1,'2015-08-17 08:45:30'),  
(4,10.00,1,1,'2015-08-17 08:45:46'),  
(5,4.00,2,1,'2015-05-17 08:44:11'),  
(6,11.00,2,1,'2015-08-17 08:44:46'),  
(7,5.00,2,1,'2015-08-17 08:45:31'),  
(9,110.00,2,2,'2015-08-17 08:46:58'),  
(10,11.00,2,2,'2015-08-17 08:47:12');
```

Expected value for product ID 1 is offer ID 7 with price 5.

These steps I think I must realize:

1. Order offers by `created` and group by `dealer_id` to get newest entries
2. Take result from step 1 and order it by price to get smallest price.
3. Make this for all products

Maybe I must use a second `SELECT FROM offer` with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` but how do I get I the `product_id` from the first (outer) select?

Comment: The most recent offer on product 1 was id 4, not id 7. Do you want latest offer, or lowest offer? If you want lowest offer, why not use id 5 with a price of 4? I don't understand.

Comment: Why didn't offer 5 win? it's for 4 dollars and an earlier time?  Is it because you want the most recent offer by dealer/product (1 each), and then pick the lowest price of those (thus picking a dealer/price)?

Answer (score 0):

This query should help you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product
JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, min(price) as minPrice, max(created) as newestOffer 
  FROM offer
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT offer_id FROM invalids)
  GROUP BY 1
) as b
ON product.id = b.product_id
```

Comment: MIN(date) will give you the oldest offer, not the newest offer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would start by getting the latest date for each product offer like this:

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(created) AS latestOffer
FROM offer
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Once you have that, you can join it to the original table to get that offer:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM offer o
JOIN(
   SELECT product_id, MAX(created) AS latestOffer
   FROM offer
   GROUP BY product_id) tmp ON tmp.product_id = o.product_id AND tmp.latestOffer = o.created;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32658/7) example.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark based on what I understand you to be after...

lots of nested subqueries.. keep thinking there's got to be a better way...

```
SELECT OO.ID, OO.Price, OO.Dealer_Id, OO.Product_ID, OO.created, P.name 
FROM Offer OO
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Min(Price) as MinP
  FROM offer O
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(OI.created) as LatestOffer, OI.Dealer_ID, OI.Product_ID 
    FROM  Offer OI
    LEFT JOIN invalids I
     on OI.Id = I.offer_Id
    WHERE I.ID is null
    GROUP BY OI.Dealer_Id, OI.Product_Id
   ) B
   on O.Dealer_Id = B.Dealer_Id
  and O.Product_Id = B.Product_Id
  and O.Created = B.LatestOffer
  ) Z
 on OO.Price = Z.MinP
INNER JOIN product P 
 on P.ID = OO.Product_ID
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c992/4/0)